# Which db is common in both flutter and android

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, android-database

i am working on an app that is bring developed in flutter i need a database that is available on both flutter and native android Right now i am using sqlite on android side and sqflite on flutter.My foreground Service Basically inserts the data in the table and on the flutter side i show that data in a listView.But Here is the issue i am facing with sqllite,i need to listen to changes being made to my tables i.e CRUD operations and listen for those changes at my flutter side:as a stream to update the UI.I read some articles on sqlbrite but as there is so little help available i dont know what to do.And i cant use FIrebase DB as my employer does not want me to use it

Comment: I am trying to understand something, do you have 2 applications? one in flutter and one in native android? Also, you can check out hiveDB which I recall has a way to notify and listen to changes occuring

Comment: no its a single app but alot of work is being done on android part as its dependent on a module written in java so

Comment: no its a single app but alot of work is being done on android part as its dependent on a module written in java so database is same ob both sides

Comment: You can manage database from Flutter side and communicate with native code by `MethodChannel` (more about how it works [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same scenario but in my case changes made to SQLite database from native reflect directly on flutter ListView using setState, here is my code:

**sms.dart (displaying the ListView from sqflite)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sqflite.dart';
    
void main() {
  runApp(SmsApp());
}

class SmsApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SmsAppState createState() => _SmsAppState();
}

class _SmsAppState extends State<SmsApp> {
  List<SMSLog>? messages;
  SMSHelper helper = new SMSHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void getMessages() async {
    await helper.open();
    final data = await helper.getAllSMS();
    setState(() {
      messages = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getMessages();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('SMS System'),
        ),
        body: messages == null
            ? Container()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: messages!.length,
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(messages![index].department),
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Another way to listen to the changes made on native side is to inform flutter using MethodChannel as stated by [fartem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10684765/fartem) in comments.